# Closing gaps between two rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have two rasters which are supposed to be perfectly aligned but they are not. There are 'gaps' between them as you can see in the picture (the white stripes are gaps):
[image]

How can I align them so that they fit? 
My first thought was to use a *resample tool* or *Align Raster* but it didn't bring the right result.

Answer (score 1):

It was a projection problem. I changed the rasters to the original CRS and now they are aligned.